# Android: Creating a ListView Adapter with an AsyncClass Object Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-asynctask

I need to store several different variables and then send them to a `ListView` `Adapter` as an Array so I can create custom rows. However, since the object that comes from the Array uses `AsyncTask` since I'm using `JSoup` and accessing the internet, I need a way to retrieve these variables in the Custom Adapter before I return the custom view back to the main class. Code is as follows:

**ListView Adapter Code:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<getProductAttributes> implements OnCallCompleteCallBack{
String title;
String price;
Bitmap image;

    //ArrayAdapter needs constructor, second parameter gets the layout for the list, third parameter is the array itself. "Context" always means background information.
    CustomAdapter(Context context, getProductAttributes[]items){
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row, items);
    }

    public void onCallComplete(int listSize, String title, String price, String imageSRC, String productURL){
         this.title=title;
         this.price = price;
         //Get Bitmap for image
         Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(imageSRC).openStream();
                mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         this.image=mIcon11;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        //One custom view is going to be equal to one row
        View customView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row,parent,false);
        ImageView productImage = (ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView itemTitle = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
        TextView itemPrice = (TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.itemPrice);

        productImage.setImageBitmap(image);
        itemTitle.setText(title);
        itemPrice.setText(price);
        return customView;

    }


}
```

**getProductAttributes class that extends AsyncTask:**

```
public class getProductAttributes extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Void> {
    OnCallCompleteCallBack callback;
    String url;
    int index;
    String productURL;
    private String price;
    private String title;
    private String imageSRC;
    ImageView productView;
    int listSize;
    int result;

public getProductAttributes(String url, int index, OnCallCompleteCallBack callback) {
    this.url = url;
    this.index = index;
    this.callback = callback;
}

protected Void doInBackground(Object... voids) {
    try{ 
      (code that gets all of the attributes, I'm sure that this code is working fine)
       }catch(Exception e){}

     return null;
    }

protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onCallComplete(listSize,title,price,imageSRC,productURL);

        }
    }
```

I think that the problem seems to be that by the time I run `onCallComplete` in the `CustomAdapter`, the customView has already been returned. If this is the case, what can I do to circumvent this?

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

> You are never calling below constructor:

```
public getProductAttributes(String url, int index, OnCallCompleteCallBack callback) {
    this.url = url;
    this.index = index;
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

> In order to let your listener object to work you have to set the `callback` object.  Also do not start your class' first letter with lower case.

Comment: How so? I am using the callback object inside the onPostExecute method, so I'm not sure what else I'm supposed to be doing since I'm also using the callback on an Activity to set the listSize and that's working fine. Also, thanks for pointing out the lower cased getProductAttributes, I hadn't even noticed it.

Comment: Your CustomAdapter class is implementing the interface: OnCallCompleteCallBack, CustomAdapter is then implementing the OnCallCompleteCallBack interface's method and this acts as a listener.  Now, in your getProductAttributes class you are using the callback OnCallCompleteCallBack  object(callback).  This object(callback) needs to be initialized by the class that is listening, in this case the CustomAdapter.

Comment: Show me where are you setting the constructor for your class "getProductAttributes".  Currently, the object  callback from:"callback.onCallComplete(listSize,title,price,imageSRC,productURL);" has a reference from the class that sets the constructor for getProductAttributes.  Your CustomAdapter  class cannot listen to "callback.onCallComplete(listSize,title,price,imageSRC,productURL);"

Comment: The constructor for getProductAttributes is in the code that I wrote above.

Comment: Where are you calling that constructor? You should have something like getProductAttributes myGetProductAtributes obj = new getProductAttributees("someurl", someindex, someObject);

Comment: There lies one of the problems, I can't specifically call getProductAttributes from CustomAdapter because it doesn't have the url variable. I understood what you were asking for I was just trying to find a way to implement it first, but I just don't see how I can do it.